# Chrome how to forget proceeding when connection is not private

Tags: google-chrome, certificate

Using Chrome 67 on Ubuntu 18.10 when accessing a site with an incorrect certificate Chrome prompts a warning about the connection not being private, as expected, and allows you the option to proceed. When you proceed it seems to remember your choice and subsequent visits to the site don't prompt to proceed again (even in incognito mode). I would like to see the certificate information Chrome presents when it prompts you to proceed - the particular server I'm accessing redirects so once I've proceeded once I can't see the certificate details with Chrome again until it automatically forgets after days/weeks(?).

Is there a way to manually ***forget*** the option to proceed so that it prompts with the warning again?

I can workaround this using Firefox (which adds exceptions permanently and allows you to delete the exception through the Privacy & Security settings, or use `curl` or `openssl s_client` but it would be good to know if it's possible to forgot per site certificate exceptions in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Click the "Not Secure" text at the left side of the address bar. It'll show options to view the certificate, or to re-enable SSL warnings.

You can use this same trick to view the (valid) certificate of a normal site.

[image]

Comment: This would be great if the site I was visiting didn't respond with a 302 and redirect immediately as I don't get chance to do the steps above and can't see a way to get Chrome to ignore the 302 temporarily.